# How a computer can infect others devices on the same network?

Tags: network, malware, virus, protection

As I said in [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206056/how-to-prevent-an-infected-pc-from-infecting-other-machines-on-the-same-network), my father is very careless about online security. Besides what I already said on that post, yesterday I saw in his android that the permission to install of third-party apps are enabled, and he confirmed that he disabled this protection to install something that he even remember what is it (I think this was recently, because he did not want to answer anything about the app's nature or when he did this). I have already talk to him about his negligence, but nothing appears to has effect.

I'm worried because my mother accesses her bank account here (in her own PC, not in my father's PC). Some members in this forum recommended to me create a separate network for me and my mother's devices, but I am have difficult to find information about how do this and I don't have knowledge about networks.

I would like to know:

1. How likely is to a virus (or any malicious program/app) spread through devices on the same network?
2. What type of malicious application can do that?
3. It is possible for me to identify if that occurs without doing a long search?

I'm accepting other suggestions about what I can do.

Obs: All devices here are windows or android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many different types of malware can spread from device to device on the network. Wannacry was a very famous recent one.

Firewalls that block incoming connections is the most basic protection against this. You should have no reason to accept incoming connections. Make sure your Windows firewalls are set up and that you are running anti-virus programs.

Android phones do not run services that you can connect to, so they do not need firewalls.

From your other post, because your router cannot provide a second network, what you need to do is to get one that does. It's just that simple.

Comment: But Wannacry is a type of malware that can easily noticed if gets infect. My principal question is if my anothers devices can get infected without I'm noticing.

Comment: Wannacry was noticed because it was designed to be noticed. That's all. If it did not display a screen, then the infection could have gone on forever without people noticing.

Comment: So, yes, you can get infected without noticing. But, that does not change my advice in my answer. A firewall blocking incoming traffic.

Comment: Can just a firewall solve this situation? Don't I have to be worry anymore?

Comment: It's an important part of the whole, and the easiest to do since you use Windows. But you really should get your father on his own network.

Comment: I forget to mention that me and my father use wired connections. It is still possible to separate him from the rest of network?

Comment: yes, absolutely

Comment: I installed a firewall and create rules to block every inbound  but a lot of blocked connections like ICMP(4 and 6) and UDP were listed in the firewall's log. Should I be worried about this connections attempts?

Comment: if they are blocked, then no.

Comment: But this is normal? They seem to come from the modem

Comment: Very normal. Modern home networks are very chatty.

Comment: very normal. all fine

Comment: schroeder, just a little question that I forgot to do: do you recommend a specific firewall?

Comment: No, we cannot make recommendations like that

Comment: between buy a new router and use this new one to my father's devices, and flash the bios of my actual modem and create a vlan or a guest network, which option is the better one? they give the same results or one is better than other?