# Isolate devices on the same network

Tags: network, isolation

I asked a similar question on [this topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206056/how-to-prevent-an-infected-pc-from-infecting-other-machines-on-the-same-network) and some guys recommended use VLANs or guest network, so I asked to a friend and he will give to me a router with guest network function. However, there is a device (my father's computer) that I want to also isolate, but guest network will not work totally since this computer use cable directly connect to the router.

This is my intranetwork currently:

```
          Another devices
                |
Internet --- Router 1 
                |     
       My father's devices
```

But I recently read that if I connect a cable from a router's LAN port to another router's WAN port, it's like isolate the devices, as devices in router 2 can connect to router 1, but not vice-versa.

This will work like this:

```
                      Another devices
                             |
Internet --- Router 1 --- Router 2
               |       
       My father's devices
```

My intention is, because security concern, isolate ALL the traffic between my father's devices and another devices in my home. So, my question is: Will the second intranetwork do that? I need, at least, that my father's devices can't communicate with another devices.

Comment: Yes this will work, provided that router#2 does NAT or has a firewall which separates the "internal" devices from the "external" ones. Note that "Router" is a very broad term which can mean lots of different things and within these lots of different configurations. Also, some "routers" actually can do guest network on LAN ports too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I don't know if I understand correctly. By default, the second intranetwork will do what I want, or do I need to configure something else?

Comment: Your full specification of the device you use is *"Router 2"*. It is completely unknown what actual device this is and how it is configured and what the defaults of this unknown device are. Therefore one cannot say if the unknown (default) configuration if the unknown device does what you need.

Comment: If both routers performs NAT and "another device" would require VPN, this configuration might break NAT traversal. Otherwise this should work, but I'd still prefer VLANs.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I know that this modem supports OpenWRT. In this case, is just one router needed to isolate the devices?

Comment: @Mycroft: I have no idea what "modem" you are talking about suddenly. A "modem" has nothing to do with network separation but this is just the connector for the physical transmission (i.e. DSL, POTS, LTE...). But if you have some hardware which can run OpenWRT you probably can separate the network best with VLAN's.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Sorry, I mean "router" :). So is it just one router running OpenWRT sufficient?

Comment: @Mycroft: If you use different VLAN's for different networks you can make sure that these networks cannot communicate with each other but still can access the internet. As far as I understand your use case this should be all you need.

Comment: @EsaJokinen  Since this router supports OpenWRT, I will use VLANs. So, in this case, is just one router running OpenWRT needed to just what I want?